# How to work with multiple models in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have two models `m1` and `m2` trained separately. Now I want to keep `m1` fixed and fine tune `m1` based on the output of `m2`. All the variables of `m1` is under the variable scope `"m1/"` and the ones of `m2` is under `"m2/"`. Here is basically what I did:

```py
# build m1 and m2
with tf.device("/cpu:0"):
    m1.build_graph()
    m2.build_graph()
# indicate the variables of m1 and m2 
allvars = tf.global_variables()
m1_vars = [v for v in allvars if v.name.startswith('m1')]
m2_vars = [v for v in allvars if v.name.startswith('m2')]
# construct the saver 
m1_saver = tf.train.Saver(m1_vars)
m2_saver = tf.train.Saver(m2_vars)
# Load m2 variables 
m2_ckpt_state = tf.train.get_checkpoint_state(FLAGS.m2_log_root)
m2_sess = tf.Session()
m2_saver.restore(m2_sess, m2_ckpt_state.model_checkpoint_path)

# construct a train supervisor for m1
m1_sv = tf.train.Supervisor(is_chief=True, saver=m1_saver)
# construct a session for m1
m1_sess =  m1_sv.prepare_or_wait_for_session()
...
```

But now there is an error in the last line of code :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "run_summarization.py", line 407, in <module>
   tf.app.run()
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 44, in run
_sys.exit(main(_sys.argv[:1] + flags_passthrough))
   File "run_summarization.py", line 401, in main run_fine_tune(model, ranker, batcher, vocab)
   File "run_summarization.py", line 232, in run_fine_tune sess_context_manager = sv.prepare_or_wait_for_session(config=config)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/supervisor.py", line 719, in prepare_or_wait_for_session
init_feed_dict=self._init_feed_dict, init_fn=self._init_fn)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/session_manager.py", line 280, in prepare_session
   self._local_init_op, msg))
   RuntimeError: Init operations did not make model ready.  Init op: init, 
   init fn: None, local_init_op: name: "group_deps"
   op: "NoOp"
   input: "^init_1"
   input: "^init_all_tables", error: Variables not initialized: m2/var1, m2/var2, m2/var3...
```

Could you please tell me why this error occurs and how can I fix it? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use separate graph for separate models; here in this case supervisor is defined with `m1_vars` but it works with the default graph where `m2_vars` also reside, when trying to initialize `m2_vars` it causes the problem. Since `m2_vars` is initialized with another session.

```
function build_graph() should be defined as
    gi = tf.Graph()
    with gi.as_default():
         ... 
         rest of the code
    return gi
with tf.device("/cpu:0"):
    g1 = m1.build_graph()
    g2 = m2.build_graph()

...
m2_sess = tf.Session(graph=g2)
...
init_op = tf.variables_initializer(m2_vars)
m1_sv = tf.train.Supervisor(graph=g1, is_chief=True, init_op=init_op, saver=m1_saver)
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer! I will have a try and get back to you soon!

Comment: Seems that it is promising. But now I am a little confused with this method. What if I want to create two graphs, for training and inference mode of the same model, `m1`. What should I do to make them share the variables? Seems different graph will maintain different set of variables. Thx

Comment: inference and training can be done using same graph. you just need to make use of the `reuse` term when defining variable.  If your graph has `dropout`/`batch_norm` you can use another parameter to your model build function `is_training`. Based on `is_training` you can reuse all the existing variables for inference without creating a new graph for inference. Also same applies to disabling dropout for inference and resuing `moving_mean` and `moving_var` for batch_norm.